# Landscaped longtable not showing the page as landscape

Tags: tables, longtable, landscape

I use the following, however the page does not come out as `landscape` and the first column title (ESG Features) is really odd, I would like it left aligned and ideally underlined if possible. To go over two pages with `longtable would be great`. I have not used `longtable` before, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be super!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begingroup
    %\centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{.5}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \tiny
    \begin{longtable}{llll}
        \caption {ESG features \\ This table reports the ESG features used in this study.}
        \toprule
            \thead[l]{ESG Features}  &  &  &  \\
            \addlinespace 
                Accidental Spills & Eco-Design Products & Internal Carbon Pricing & Renewable Energy Produced \\
                Accidents Total & Electricity Produced & Internal Promotion & Renewable Energy Purchased \\
                Accounting Controversies & Electricity Purchased & ISO 14000 or EMS & Renewable Energy Use \\
                Advance Notice for Shareholder Proposals & Elimination of Cumulative Voting Rights & ISO 9000 & Renewable Energy Use Ratio \\
                Advance Notice Period Days & Embryonic Stem Cell Research & Labeled Wood & Renewable/Clean Energy Products \\
                Agrochemical 5 \% Revenue & Emissions Score & Land Environmental Impact Reduction & Resource Reduction Policy \\
                Agrochemical Products & Emissions Trading & Limitation of Director Liability & Resource Reduction Targets \\
                Alcohol & Employee Accidents & Limitations on Removal of Directors & Resource Use Score \\
                Animal Testing & Employee Engagement Voluntary Work & Limited Shareholder Rights to Call Meetings & Responsible Marketing Controversies \\
                Animal Testing Cosmetics & Employee Fatalities & Litigation Expenses & Retailing Responsibility \\
                Animal Testing Reduction & Employee Health  Safety Training Hours & Lobbying Contribution Amount & Salary Gap \\
                Announced Layoffs & Employee Lost Working Days & Lost Days To Total Days & Self-Reported Environmental Fines \\
                Announced Layoffs To Total Employees & Employee Resource Groups & Lost Time Injury Rate Contractors & Shareholder Approval Significant Transactions \\
                Anti Takeover Devices Above Two & Employee Satisfaction & Lost Time Injury Rate Employees & Shareholder Rights Policy \\
                Anti-competition Controversies & Employees Health  Safety Controversies & Lost Time Injury Rate Total & Shareholders Approval Stock Compensation Plan \\
                Anti-Competition Controversies Count & Employees Health  Safety OHSAS 18001 & Lost Working Days & Shareholders Score \\
                Anti-Personnel Landmines & Employees Health  Safety Team & Management Departures & Shareholders Vote on Executive Pay \\
                Armaments & Employees With Disabilities & Management Score & Six Sigma and Quality Mgt Systems \\
                Audit Board Committee & EMS Certified Percent & Management Training & Social Pillar Score \\
                Audit Committee Expertise & Energy Produced Direct & Minimum Number of Shares to Vote & SOx Emissions \\
                Audit Committee Independence & Energy Purchased Direct & Net Employment Creation & Staff Transportation Impact Reduction \\
                Audit Committee Mgt Independence & Energy Use Total & New Women Employees & Staggered Board Structure \\
                Audit Committee NonExecutive Members & Env Supply Chain Partnership Termination & Noise Reduction & Stakeholder Engagement \\
                Auditor Tenure & Environment Management Team & Nomination Board Committee & State Owned Enterprise SOE \\
                Average Board Tenure & Environment Management Training & Nomination Committee Independence & Strictly Independent Board Members \\
                Average Training Hours & Environment Pillar Score & Nomination Committee Involvement & Strikes \\
                Biodiversity Impact Reduction & Environmental Assets Under Mgt & Nomination Committee Mgt Independence & Succession Plan \\
                Board Attendance & Environmental Controversies & Nomination Committee NonExecutive Members & Supermajority Vote Requirement \\
                Board Background and Skills & Environmental Expenditures & Non-audit to Audit Fees Ratio & Supplier ESG training \\
                Board Cultural Diversity, Percent & Environmental Expenditures Investments & Non-Executive Board Members & Supply Chain Health  Safety Improvements \\
                Board Functions Policy & Environmental Innovation Score & Non-Hazardous Waste & Supply Chain Health  Safety Training \\
                Board Gender Diversity, Percent & Environmental Investments Initiatives & NOx and SOx Emissions Reduction & Sustainability Compensation Incentives \\
                Board Individual Re-election & Environmental Materials Sourcing & NOx Emissions & Sustainable Building Products \\
                Board Meeting Attendance Average & Environmental Partnerships & Nuclear & Take-back and Recycling Initiatives \\
                Board Member Affiliations & Environmental Products & Number of Board Meetings & Targets Diversity and Opportunity \\
                Board Member Compensation & Environmental Project Financing & Number of Employees~ from CSR reporting & Targets Emissions \\
                Board Member LT Compensation Incentives & Environmental Provisions & Obesity Risk & Targets Energy Efficiency \\
                Board Member Membership Limits & Environmental Restoration Initiatives & Occupational Diseases & Targets Water Efficiency \\
                Board Member Term Duration & Environmental Supply Chain Management & OECD Guidelines for Multinational Enterprises & Tobacco \\
                Board Size & Environmental Supply Chain Monitoring & Organic Products Initiatives & Total CO2 Equivalent Emissions To Revenues USD \\
                Board Size More Ten Less Eight & Equal Shareholder Rights & Ozone-Depleting Substances & Total Donations To Revenues \\
                Board Specific Skills, Percent & Equator Principles & Particulate Matter Emissions Reduction & Total Energy Use To Revenues USD \\
                Board Structure Policy & ESG Combined Score & Poison Pill & Total Hazardous Waste To Revenues USD \\
                Board Structure Type & ESG Controversies Score & Policy Board Diversity & Total Injury Rate Employees \\
                Bribery, Corruption and Fraud Controversies & ESG Reporting Scope & Policy Board Experience & Total Injury Rate Total \\
                Business Ethics Controversies & ESG Score & Policy Board Independence & Total Senior Executives Compensation \\
                CEO Board Member & Estimated CO2 Equivalents Emission Total & Policy Board Size & Total Waste To Revenues USD \\
                CEO Compensation Link to TSR & Ethical Trading Initiative ETI & Policy Bribery and Corruption & Toxic Chemicals Reduction \\
                CEO-Chairman Separation & Executive Compensation Controversies & Policy Business Ethics & Trade Union Representation \\
                Chairman is ex-CEO & Executive Compensation LT Objectives & Policy Career Development & Training and Development Policy \\
                Classified Board Structure & Executive Compensation Policy & Policy Child Labor & Training Costs Per Employee \\
                Climate Change Commercial Risks Opportunities & Executive Individual Compensation & Policy Community Involvement & Training Costs Total \\
                Cluster Bombs & Executive Members Gender Diversity, Percent & Policy Customer Health  Safety & Training Hours Total \\
                CO2 Equivalent Emissions Direct, Scope 1 & Executives Cultural Diversity & Policy Data Privacy & TRDIR Controversies Score \\
                CO2 Equivalent Emissions Indirect, Scope 2 & External Consultants & Policy Diversity and Opportunity & TRDIR Diversity Score \\
                CO2 Equivalent Emissions Indirect, Scope 3 & Extractive Industries Transparency Initiative & Policy Emissions & TRDIR Inclusion Score \\
                CO2 Equivalent Emissions Total & Fair Price Provision & Policy Employee Health  Safety & TRDIR People Development Score \\
                CO2 Estimation Method & Firearms & Policy Energy Efficiency & TRDIR Score \\
                Committee Meetings Attendance Average & Flexible Working Hours & Policy Environmental Supply Chain & Turnover of Employees \\
                Community Score & Fossil Fuel Divestment Policy & Policy Equal Voting Right & Unlimited Authorized Capital or Blank Check \\
                Company Cross Shareholding & Fresh Water Withdrawal Total & Policy Executive Compensation ESG Performance & UNPRI Signatory \\
                Compensation Board Committee & Fundamental Human Rights ILO UN & Policy Executive Compensation Performance & Veto Power or Golden share \\
                Compensation Committee Independence & Gambling & Policy Executive Retention & VOC Emissions \\
                Compensation Committee Mgt Independence & Global Compact Signatory & Policy Fair Competition & VOC Emissions Reduction \\
                Compensation Committee NonExecutive Members & GMO Products & Policy Fair Trade & VOC or Particulate Matter Emissions Reduction \\
                Compensation Improvement Tools & Golden Parachute & Policy Forced Labor & Voting Cap \\
                Confidential Voting Policy & Governance Pillar Score & Policy Freedom of Association & Voting Cap Percentage \\
                Consumer Complaints Controversies & Green Buildings & Policy Human Rights & Wages Working Condition Controversies \\
                Consumer Complaints Controversies Count & GRI Report Guidelines & Policy Responsible Marketing & Wages Working Condition Controversies Count \\
                Contraceptives & Hazardous Waste & Policy Shareholder Engagement & Waste Recycled To Total Waste \\
                Contractor Fatalities & Health  Safety Policy & Policy Skills Training & Waste Recycled Total \\
                Corporate Governance Board Committee & Health  Safety Training & Policy Supply Chain Health  Safety & Waste Recycling Ratio \\
                Corporate Responsibility Awards & Healthy Food or Products & Policy Sustainable Packaging & Waste Reduction Initiatives \\
                Crisis Management Systems & Highest Remuneration Package & Policy Water Efficiency & Waste Total \\
                CSR Strategy Score & HIV-AIDS Program & Political Contributions & Water Discharged \\
                CSR Sustainability Committee & HRC Corporate Equality Index & Pornography & Water Pollutant Emissions \\
                CSR Sustainability External Audit & Human Rights Breaches Contractor & Pre-emptive Rights & Water Pollutant Emissions To Revenues USD \\
                CSR Sustainability Report Global Activities & Human Rights Contractor & Product Access Low Price & Water Recycled \\
                CSR Sustainability Reporting & Human Rights Policy & Product Environmental Responsible Use & Water Technologies \\
                Customer Satisfaction & Human Rights Score & Product Impact Minimization & Water Use To Revenues USD \\
                Day Care Services & Hybrid Vehicles & Product Quality Controversies & Water Withdrawal Total \\
                Different Voting Right Share & Improvement Tools Business Ethics & Product Recall & Whistleblower Protection \\
                Director Election Majority Requirement & Independent Board Members & Product Responsibility Monitoring & Women Employees \\
                Diseases of the Developing World & Injuries To Million Hours & Product Responsibility Score & Women Managers \\
                Diversity and Opportunity Controversies & Insider Dealings Controversies & Product Sales at Discount to Emerging Markets & Workforce Score \\
                Donations Total & Integrated Strategy in MDA & Profit Warnings & Written Consent Requirements \\
                e-Waste Reduction & Intellectual Property Controversies & Public Availability Corporate Statutes &  \\
                Earnings Restatement & Internal Audit Department Reporting & Quality Mgt Systems \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{longtable}
\endgroup
    \end{landscape}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: In your MWE are missed packages `booktabs` and `makecell`. Missed is also termination of `\caption{...}` by `\\ ` after it. Beside this  table is almost unreadable due to `\tiny` font size. You should reconsider if this alphabetically ordered data is appropriate to present in a four table. To my opinion it will be better to present them in two column with normal font size.

Comment: Every environment (at least \begin and \end) is a group, so the \begingroup...\endgroup is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Since your table is not really a table but more a list, I suggest using an `itemize` environment. In order to save space, I placed the `itemize` inside of a `multicols` environment. If you also adjust the spacing of tie `itemize` list, as well as the font size to `\small`, the whole list fits onto a total of 4 pages while still being at a readable font size.

(Unrelated, but I also used `\ch` from `chemformula` in order to get the correct subscript "2" in CO2)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}


\begin{multicols}{2}
\small
\begin{itemize}[nosep,leftmargin=*,labelsep=3pt]
\item  Accidental Spills   
\item  Accidents Total    
\item  Accounting Controversies    
\item  Advance Notice for Shareholder Proposals    
\item  Advance Notice Period Days    
\item  Agrochemical 5 \% Revenue    
\item  Agrochemical Products    
\item  Alcohol    
\item  Animal Testing    
\item  Animal Testing Cosmetics   
\item  Animal Testing Reduction   
\item  Announced Layoffs   
\item  Announced Layoffs To Total Employees    
\item  Anti Takeover Devices Above Two   
\item  Anti-competition Controversies   
\item  Anti-Competition Controversies Count   
\item  Anti-Personnel Landmines   
\item  Armaments  
\item  Audit Board Committee   
\item  Audit Committee Expertise   
\item  Audit Committee Independence   
\item  Audit Committee Mgt Independence  
\item  Audit Committee NonExecutive Members   
\item  Auditor Tenure  
\item  Average Board Tenure  
\item  Average Training Hours  
\item  Biodiversity Impact Reduction   
\item  Board Attendance  
\item  Board Background and Skills  
\item  Board Cultural Diversity, Percent  
\item  Board Functions Policy  
\item  Board Gender Diversity, Percent  
\item  Board Individual Re-election  
\item  Board Meeting Attendance Average  
\item  Board Member Affiliations  
\item  Board Member Compensation  
\item  Board Member LT Compensation Incentives  
\item  Board Member Membership Limits  
\item  Board Member Term Duration  
\item  Board Size  
\item  Board Size More Ten Less Eight 
\item  Board Specific Skills, Percent  
\item  Board Structure Policy  
\item  Board Structure Type   
\item  Bribery, Corruption and Fraud Controversies  
\item  Business Ethics Controversies  
\item  CEO Board Member  
\item  CEO Compensation Link to TSR  
\item  CEO-Chairman Separation 
\item  Chairman is ex-CEO  
\item  Classified Board Structure  
\item  Climate Change Commercial Risks Opportunities  
\item  Cluster Bombs  
\item  \ch{CO2} Equivalent Emissions Direct, Scope 1  
\item  \ch{CO2} Equivalent Emissions Indirect, Scope 2  
\item  \ch{CO2} Equivalent Emissions Indirect, Scope 3  
\item  \ch{CO2} Equivalent Emissions Total   
\item  \ch{CO2} Estimation Method   
\item  Committee Meetings Attendance Average  
\item  Community Score   
\item  Company Cross Shareholding   
\item  Compensation Board Committee   
\item  Compensation Committee Independence  
\item  Compensation Committee Mgt Independence  
\item  Compensation Committee NonExecutive Members   
\item  Compensation Improvement Tools  
\item  Confidential Voting Policy   
\item  Consumer Complaints Controversies  
\item  Consumer Complaints Controversies Count   
\item  Contraceptives   
\item  Contractor Fatalities   
\item  Corporate Governance Board Committee   
\item  Corporate Responsibility Awards   
\item  Crisis Management Systems  
\item  CSR Strategy Score   
\item  CSR Sustainability Committee   
\item  CSR Sustainability External Audit  
\item  CSR Sustainability Report Global Activities  
\item  CSR Sustainability Reporting   
\item  Customer Satisfaction   
\item  Day Care Services   
\item  Different Voting Right Share  
\item  Director Election Majority Requirement   
\item  Diseases of the Developing World  
\item  Diversity and Opportunity Controversies   
\item  Donations Total   
\item  e-Waste Reduction    
\item  Earnings Restatement  
\item  Eco-Design Products                         
\item  Electricity Produced                        
\item  Electricity Purchased                       
\item  Elimination of Cumulative Voting Rights     
\item  Embryonic Stem Cell Research                
\item  Emissions Score                             
\item  Emissions Trading                           
\item  Employee Accidents                          
\item  Employee Engagement Voluntary Work          
\item  Employee Fatalities                         
\item  Employee Health  Safety Training Hours      
\item  Employee Lost Working Days                  
\item  Employee Resource Groups                    
\item  Employee Satisfaction                       
\item  Employees Health  Safety Controversies      
\item  Employees Health  Safety OHSAS 18001        
\item  Employees Health  Safety Team               
\item  Employees With Disabilities                 
\item  EMS Certified Percent                       
\item  Energy Produced Direct                      
\item  Energy Purchased Direct                     
\item  Energy Use Total                            
\item  Env Supply Chain Partnership Termination    
\item  Environment Management Team                 
\item  Environment Management Training             
\item  Environment Pillar Score                    
\item  Environmental Assets Under Mgt              
\item  Environmental Controversies                 
\item  Environmental Expenditures                  
\item  Environmental Expenditures Investments      
\item  Environmental Innovation Score              
\item  Environmental Investments Initiatives       
\item  Environmental Materials Sourcing            
\item  Environmental Partnerships                  
\item  Environmental Products                      
\item  Environmental Project Financing             
\item  Environmental Provisions                    
\item  Environmental Restoration Initiatives       
\item  Environmental Supply Chain Management       
\item  Environmental Supply Chain Monitoring       
\item  Equal Shareholder Rights                    
\item  Equator Principles                          
\item  ESG Combined Score                          
\item  ESG Controversies Score                     
\item  ESG Reporting Scope                         
\item  ESG Score                                   
\item  Estimated \ch{CO2} Equivalents Emission Total    
\item  Ethical Trading Initiative ETI              
\item  Executive Compensation Controversies        
\item  Executive Compensation LT Objectives        
\item  Executive Compensation Policy               
\item  Executive Individual Compensation           
\item  Executive Members Gender Diversity, Percent 
\item  Executives Cultural Diversity               
\item  External Consultants                        
\item  Extractive Industries Transparency Initiative 
\item  Fair Price Provision                          
\item  Firearms                                      
\item  Flexible Working Hours                        
\item  Fossil Fuel Divestment Policy                 
\item  Fresh Water Withdrawal Total                  
\item  Fundamental Human Rights ILO UN               
\item  Gambling                                      
\item  Global Compact Signatory                      
\item  GMO Products                                  
\item  Golden Parachute                              
\item  Governance Pillar Score                       
\item  Green Buildings                               
\item  GRI Report Guidelines                         
\item  Hazardous Waste                               
\item  Health  Safety Policy                         
\item  Health  Safety Training                       
\item  Healthy Food or Products                      
\item  Highest Remuneration Package                  
\item  HIV-AIDS Program                              
\item  HRC Corporate Equality Index                  
\item  Human Rights Breaches Contractor              
\item  Human Rights Contractor                       
\item  Human Rights Policy                           
\item  Human Rights Score                            
\item  Hybrid Vehicles                               
\item  Improvement Tools Business Ethics             
\item  Independent Board Members                     
\item  Injuries To Million Hours                     
\item  Insider Dealings Controversies                
\item  Integrated Strategy in MDA  Profit Warnings  
\item  Intellectual Property Controversies           
\item  Internal Audit Department Reporting           
\item  Internal Carbon Pricing                            
\item  Internal Promotion                                      
\item  ISO 14000 or EMS                                          
\item  Lost Time Injury Rate Contractors             
\item  Labeled Wood                                                  
\item  Land Environmental Impact Reduction           
\item  Limitation of Director Liability              
\item  Limitations on Removal of Directors           
\item  Limited Shareholder Rights to Call Meetings   
\item  Litigation Expenses                                    
\item  Lobbying Contribution Amount                  
\item  Lost Days To Total Days                            
\item  Lost Time Injury Rate Contractors             
\item  Lost Time Injury Rate Employees               
\item  Lost Time Injury Rate Total                    
\item  Lost Working Days                                        
\item  Management Departures                                
\item  Management Score                                          
\item  Management Training                                    
\item  Minimum Number of Shares to Vote              
\item  Net Employment Creation                            
\item  New Women Employees                                    
\item  Noise Reduction                                            
\item  Nomination Board Committee                      
\item  Nomination Committee Independence             
\item  Nomination Committee Involvement              
\item  Nomination Committee Mgt Independence         
\item  Nomination Committee NonExecutive Members      
\item  Non-audit to Audit Fees Ratio                  
\item  Non-Executive Board Members                     
\item  Non-Hazardous Waste                                     
\item  NOx and SOx Emissions Reduction                
\item  NOx Emissions                                                 
\item  Nuclear                                                             
\item  Number of Board Meetings                           
\item  Number of Employees from CSR reporting         
\item  Obesity Risk                                                   
\item  Occupational Diseases                                 
\item  OECD Guidelines for Multinational Enterprises  
\item  Organic Products Initiatives                   
\item  Ozone-Depleting Substances                       
\item  Particulate Matter Emissions Reduction         
\item  Poison Pill                                                     
\item  Policy Board Diversity                               
\item  Policy Board Experience                             
\item  Policy Board Independence                         
\item  Policy Board Size                                         
\item  Policy Bribery and Corruption                  
\item  Policy Business Ethics                               
\item  Policy Career Development                         
\item  Policy Child Labor                                       
\item  Policy Community Involvement                   
\item  Policy Customer Health  Safety                 
\item  Policy Data Privacy                                     
\item  Policy Diversity and Opportunity               
\item  Policy Emissions                                       
\item  Policy Employee Health  Safety                 
\item  Policy Energy Efficiency                      
\item  Policy Environmental Supply Chain             
\item  Policy Equal Voting Right                     
\item  Policy Executive Compensation ESG Performance 
\item  Policy Executive Compensation Performance     
\item  Policy Executive Retention                    
\item  Policy Fair Competition                        
\item  Policy Fair Trade                                    
\item  Policy Forced Labor                                
\item  Policy Freedom of Association                 
\item  Policy Human Rights                                
\item  Policy Responsible Marketing                  
\item  Policy Shareholder Engagement                 
\item  Policy Skills Training                          
\item  Policy Supply Chain Health  Safety            
\item  Policy Sustainable Packaging                  
\item  Policy Water Efficiency                        
\item  Political Contributions                        
\item  Pornography                                                
\item  Pre-emptive Rights                                  
\item  Product Access Low Price                      
\item  Product Environmental Responsible Use         
\item  Product Impact Minimization                   
\item  Product Quality Controversies                 
\item  Product Recall                                          
\item  Product Responsibility Monitoring             
\item  Product Responsibility Score                  
\item  Product Sales at Discount to Emerging Markets 
\item  Written Consent Requirements                                                           
\item  Public Availability Corporate Statutes                                                 
\item  Quality Mgt Systems                                                                    
\item  Renewable Energy Produced                                   
\item  Renewable Energy Purchased                                  
\item  Renewable Energy Use                                        
\item  Shareholder Approval Significant Transactions               
\item  Renewable/Clean Energy Products                             
\item  Resource Reduction Policy                                   
\item  Resource Reduction Targets                                  
\item  Resource Use Score                                          
\item  Responsible Marketing Controversies                         
\item  Retailing Responsibility                                    
\item  Salary Gap                                                  
\item  Self-Reported Environmental Fines                           
\item  Shareholder Approval Significant Transactions               
\item  Shareholder Rights Policy                                   
\item  Shareholders Approval Stock Compensation Plan               
\item  Shareholders Score                                          
\item  Shareholders Vote on Executive Pay                          
\item  Six Sigma and Quality Mgt Systems                           
\item  Social Pillar Score                                         
\item  SOx Emissions                                               
\item  Staff Transportation Impact Reduction                       
\item  Staggered Board Structure                                   
\item  Stakeholder Engagement                                      
\item  State Owned Enterprise SOE                                  
\item  Strictly Independent Board Members                          
\item  Strikes                                                     
\item  Succession Plan                                             
\item  Supermajority Vote Requirement                              
\item  Supplier ESG training                                       
\item  Supply Chain Health  Safety Improvements                    
\item  Supply Chain Health  Safety Training                        
\item  Sustainability Compensation Incentives                      
\item  Sustainable Building Products                               
\item  Take-back and Recycling Initiatives                         
\item  Targets Diversity and Opportunity                           
\item  Targets Emissions                                           
\item  Targets Energy Efficiency                                   
\item  Targets Water Efficiency                                    
\item  Tobacco                                                     
\item  Total \ch{CO2} Equivalent Emissions To Revenues USD              
\item  Total Donations To Revenues                                 
\item  Total Energy Use To Revenues USD
\item  Total Hazardous Waste To Revenues USD
\item  Total Injury Rate Employees
\item  Total Injury Rate Total
\item  Total Senior Executives Compensation
\item  Total Waste To Revenues USD
\item  Toxic Chemicals Reduction
\item  Trade Union Representation
\item  Training and Development Policy
\item  Training Costs Per Employee
\item  Training Costs Total
\item  Training Hours Total
\item  TRDIR Controversies Score
\item  TRDIR Diversity Score
\item  TRDIR Inclusion Score
\item  TRDIR People Development Score       
\item  TRDIR Score       
\item  Turnover of Employees      
\item  Unlimited Authorized Capital or Blank Check   
\item  UNPRI Signatory    
\item  Veto Power or Golden share    
\item  VOC Emissions    
\item  VOC Emissions Reduction     
\item  VOC or Particulate Matter Emissions Reduction
\item  Voting Cap     
\item  Voting Cap Percentage          
\item  Wages Working Condition Controversies
\item  Wages Working Condition Controversies Count
\item  Waste Recycled To Total Waste
\item  Waste Recycled Total
\item  Waste Recycling Ratio
\item  Waste Reduction Initiatives
\item  Waste Total
\item  Water Discharged
\item  Water Pollutant Emissions
\item  Water Pollutant Emissions To Revenues USD
\item  Water Recycled
\item  Water Technologies
\item  Water Use To Revenues USD
\item  Water Withdrawal Total
\item  Whistleblower Protection
\item  Women Employees
\item  Women Managers
\item  Workforce Score 

                                   
\end{itemize}  
\end{multicols}  

\end{document}
```

---

Update: Here is a suggestion using a 4 column list, `\footnotesize` text and smaller margins in order to fit all contents onto two pages. I also added the caption using the `\captionof` command from the `caption` package. (The following MWE is shortened due to character limit in posts on this site.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\newgeometry{margin=2.25cm}
\begingroup

\captionof{table}{This table reports the ESG features used in this study.}

\hrule
\footnotesize 
\raggedright
\begin{multicols}{4}
\begin{itemize}[nosep,leftmargin=*,labelsep=3pt]
\item  Accidental Spills   
\item  Accidents Total    
\item  Accounting Controversies    
\item  Advance Notice for Shareholder Proposals    
\item  Advance Notice Period Days    
\item  Agrochemical 5 \% Revenue    
\item  Agrochemical Products    
\item  Alcohol    
\item  Animal Testing    
\item  Animal Testing Cosmetics   
\item  Animal Testing Reduction   
\item  Announced Layoffs   
\item  Announced Layoffs To Total Employees    
\item  Anti Takeover Devices Above Two   
\item  Anti-competition Controversies   
\item  Anti-Competition Controversies Count   
\item  Anti-Personnel Landmines   
\item  Armaments  
\item  Audit Board Committee   
\item  Audit Committee Expertise   
\item  Audit Committee Independence   
\item  Audit Committee Mgt Independence  
\item  Audit Committee NonExecutive Members   
\item  Auditor Tenure  
\item  Average Board Tenure  
\item  Average Training Hours  
\item  Biodiversity Impact Reduction   
\item  Board Attendance  
\item  Board Background and Skills  
\item  Board Cultural Diversity, Percent  
\item  Board Functions Policy  
\item  Board Gender Diversity, Percent  
\item  Board Individual Re-election  
\item  Board Meeting Attendance Average  
\item  Board Member Affiliations  
\item  Board Member Compensation  
\item  Board Member LT Compensation Incentives  
\item  Board Member Membership Limits  
\item  Board Member Term Duration  
\item  Board Size  
\item  Board Size More Ten Less Eight 
\item  Board Specific Skills, Percent  
\item  Board Structure Policy  
\item  Board Structure Type   
\item  Bribery, Corruption and Fraud Controversies  
\item  Business Ethics Controversies  
\item  CEO Board Member  
\item  CEO Compensation Link to TSR  
\item  CEO-Chairman Separation 
\item  Chairman is ex-CEO  
\item  Classified Board Structure  
\item  Climate Change Commercial Risks Opportunities  
\item  Cluster Bombs  
\item  \ch{CO2} Equivalent Emissions Direct, Scope 1  
\item  \ch{CO2} Equivalent Emissions Indirect, Scope 2  
\item  \ch{CO2} Equivalent Emissions Indirect, Scope 3  
\item  \ch{CO2} Equivalent Emissions Total   
\item  \ch{CO2} Estimation Method   
\item  Committee Meetings Attendance Average  
\item  Community Score   
\item  Company Cross Shareholding   
\item  Compensation Board Committee   
\item  Compensation Committee Independence  
\item  Compensation Committee Mgt Independence  
\item  Compensation Committee NonExecutive Members   
\item  Compensation Improvement Tools  
\item  Confidential Voting Policy   
\item  Consumer Complaints Controversies  
\item  Consumer Complaints Controversies Count   
\item  Contraceptives   
\item  Contractor Fatalities   
\item  Corporate Governance Board Committee   
\item  Corporate Responsibility Awards   
\item  Crisis Management Systems  
\item  CSR Strategy Score   
\item  CSR Sustainability Committee   
\item  CSR Sustainability External Audit  
\item  CSR Sustainability Report Global Activities  
\item  CSR Sustainability Reporting   
\item  Customer Satisfaction   
\item  Day Care Services   
\item  Different Voting Right Share  
\item  Director Election Majority Requirement   
\item  Diseases of the Developing World  
\item  Diversity and Opportunity Controversies   
\item  Donations Total   
\item  e-Waste Reduction    
\item  Earnings Restatement  
\item  Eco-Design Products                         
\item  Electricity Produced                        
\item  Electricity Purchased                       
\item  Elimination of Cumulative Voting Rights     
\item  Embryonic Stem Cell Research                
\item  Emissions Score                             
\item  Emissions Trading                           
\item  Employee Accidents                          
\item  Employee Engagement Voluntary Work          
\item  Employee Fatalities                         
\item  Employee Health  Safety Training Hours      
\item  Employee Lost Working Days                  
\item  Employee Resource Groups                    
\item  Employee Satisfaction                       
\item  Employees Health  Safety Controversies      
\item  Employees Health  Safety OHSAS 18001        
\item  Employees Health  Safety Team               
\item  Employees With Disabilities                 
\item  EMS Certified Percent                       
\item  Energy Produced Direct                      
\item  Energy Purchased Direct                     
\item  Energy Use Total                            
\item  Env Supply Chain Partnership Termination    
\item  Environment Management Team                 
\item  Environment Management Training             
\item  Environment Pillar Score                    
\item  Environmental Assets Under Mgt              
\item  Environmental Controversies                 
\item  Environmental Expenditures                  
\item  Environmental Expenditures Investments      
\item  Environmental Innovation Score              
\item  Environmental Investments Initiatives       
\item  Environmental Materials Sourcing            
\item  Environmental Partnerships                  
\item  Environmental Products                      
\item  Environmental Project Financing             
\item  Environmental Provisions                    
\item  Environmental Restoration Initiatives       
\item  Environmental Supply Chain Management       
\item  Environmental Supply Chain Monitoring       
\item  Equal Shareholder Rights                    
\item  Equator Principles                          
\item  ESG Combined Score                          
\item  ESG Controversies Score                     
\item  ESG Reporting Scope                                                                  
\end{itemize}  
\end{multicols} 
\hrule
\clearpage
\endgroup
\restoregeometry

\lipsum  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, really interesting how you made that, however, a table over two pages is required and not a list over four

Comment: @oceanbeach96: Be it a table or a list, I honestly doubt you will ever be able to fit all this information onto just tow pages while still keeping the font size at lease somewhat readable. Can you change the margins?

Comment: @oceanbeach96: I have added an alternative solution with which you can fit all the information onto two pages using a 4 column listand significantly decreased margins. Probably this is closer to the desired output.